# AWS S3 Bucket as an internal website for documentation with automatic updates from CI

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci

I want to make an S3 bucket that receives internal documentation from Travis-CI whenever we build master which works fine on Travis-CI. However, I want to limit the internal documentation to only be visible to our company IPs which are static. The policy I am trying to use is the following.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "InternalDocs",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Docs User",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/docs"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::docs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::docs/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Whitelisted Read",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::docs/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "000000000000"
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "0.0.0.0/32",
                        "0.0.0.0/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that `0.0.0.0`, `000000000000`, `arn:aws:s3:::docs` and `arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/docs` are placeholders because I don't want to show our actual names, ids or IPs.

The problem I end up with is that since `"Principal": "*"` seems to match any user, public or not public it will then end up blocking everything. The result is that anyone from the company's static ip can access the bucket but Travis-CI is blocked from uploading new versions of the docs to the bucket.

**How can I allow Travis-CI to upload to my S3 bucket while still only allowing specifc IPs to view the documentation using `s3:GetObject` while blocking anyone else?**

I use the deploy function on Travis-CI with the AWS access key and access secret for the user `arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/docs`.

Comment: `aws:userid` is not a number, it's a string that begins with `AIDA`.  Are you using the correct value, there?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It seems like you are right, I am still testing the policy but adding a wildcard for the userid seems to have made things work as expected.